# PHP - check if array keys of two arrays match

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to check two arrays for a certain key. If the key in both arrays matches I want to get it returned.
Here is a small example:

```
$array1 = ['one', 'helpMe!!', 'danger', 'correctKey'];
$array2 = ['correctKey'];
$result = some_method($array1, $array2); //Should return the string 'correctKey'
```

Of course you just could iterate over `$array1` and check if the key matches, but I want to use a simple function that PHP maybe already provides.

Iteration:

```
foreach ($array1 as $arrayKey) {
    if ($array2['correctKey'] === $arrayKey) {
        $result = $arrayKey;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1. Those aren't keys 2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 0):

`array_intersect` is what you are looking for:

```
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `array_intersect()`:

```
$array1 = ['one', 'helpMe!!', 'danger', 'correctKey'];
$array2 = ['correctKey'];

$matches = array_intersect($array1, $array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking the common keys in two arrays, as specified in the title:

```
$arr1 = [...];
$arr2 = [...];

$result  = array_intersect(array_keys($arr1), array_keys($arr2));
```

Even simpler, just as pointed out by [AbraCadaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2844319/abracadaver), use this

```
$result  = array_intersect_key($arr1, $arr2));
```

Comment: Or just `array_intersect_key()`